# Passing multiple lambda functions in Pandas.DataFrame.transform in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is the code (in python)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_5 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(3), 'B': range(1, 4)})
df_5.transform([lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3])
```

and see the DataFrame for reference

[image: DataFrame]

this is the output (It just does the 2nd thing `lambda x: x**3`)

[image: My output]

but I want it to look like this (where Both the columns have been both `lambda x: x**2` and `lambda x: x**3`)

[image: Correct output]

so what changes should I make to the last line `df_5.transform([lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df_5.apply([lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3])
print (df)
         A                 B         
  <lambda> <lambda> <lambda> <lambda>
0        0        0        1        1
1        1        1        4        8
2        4        8        9       27
```

If `transform` is necessary:

```
df = pd.concat([df_5.transform([lambda x: x**2]), 
                df_5.transform([lambda x: x**3])],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    
print (df)
         A                 B         
  <lambda> <lambda> <lambda> <lambda>
0        0        0        1        1
1        1        1        4        8
2        4        8        9       27
```

Comment: But can you do it using `DataFrame.transform` because In the course that I was using he used `DataFrame.transform` only

Comment: I think not possible here what you need by one `transform`, need 2 times and `concat`